# Подчиненное предложение или дополнение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, дополнение, подчинительная-связь

> Правило задает(,) от какого источника каким получателям передать данные.

Коллега утверждает, что запятая не нужна, так как после спорного места нет предложения, следовательно, это дополнение и оно ни по какому правилу не обособляется. Я не могу назвать точное правило, но "книжная грамотность" протестует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы правы, запятая нужна:
*Правило задает, от какого источника каким получателям передать данные.*

Это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух. Первое – главное, второе – придаточное. Последнее является [безличным предложением](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-bezlichnyih-predlozheniy.html) (подлежащего нет).

[***Сложноподчиненные предложения с придаточными изъяснительными***](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#42102) (Грамота.ру)

> Придаточные изъяснительные отвечают на падежные вопросы и присоединяются к главной части **союзами** (*что, как, будто, как будто, как бы, чтобы, ли, не — ли, ли — или, то ли — то ли* и др.) и **союзными словами** (*что, кто, как, какой, почему, где, куда, откуда, зачем* и др.).

*Правило задает* [**что?**], *от какого источника каким получателям передать данные.*
В данном случае придаточное предложение занимает позицию дополнения, поэтому такие предложения ещё называют придаточными дополнительными.

Comment: Мне кажется, что дополнительные предложения немного другие, это уже местоименная связь ТО – ЧТО, например: Я увидел то, что другие не видели. А здесь изъяснительная связь, но скорее вмещающего типа (опорное слово не ментального характера). Но эти тонкости не так важны, если нужно дополнение (член предложения) отличить от предложения.

Comment: @Sharon Если бы в вопросе не было слова "дополнение", я бы об этом вообще не писал. На Грамоте.ру говорят о двух классификациях, по одной из которых "придаточные делятся на подлежащные, сказуемные, определительные, дополнительные и обстоятельственные в зависимости от того, какой член предложения замещен придаточным предложением". А в разделе об изъяснит. придаточных написано: "В главной части может находиться указательное слово ***то***...", которое может быть опущено или, наоборот, обязательно.  "Эта особенность [обязательность] сближает такие предложения с местоименно-определительными..."

Comment: Вообще говоря, классификации могу быть разные (по разным признакам), тут удивляться не приходится.  Классификации с Грамоты.ру применяется далеко не всегда.  Можно вспомнить школьную или вузовскую классификацию, они другие. Местоименное слово? Тоже скользкая вещь. В изъяснительных предложениях оно факультативное, в местоименно-определительных  необходимое, во вмещающих изъяснительных  зависит от стиля (обязательно, но в разговорном стиле пропускается).

Comment: Но это все верно, если в микроскоп рассматривать)  А здесь это не требовалось. Но я все-таки не стала  бы использовать «дополнительное предложение», чтобы никто не цеплялся (этот термин применяется не часто и выглядит неоднозначно).  P.S.Предлагаю всё удалить))

Comment: @Sharon  Зачем удалять? Не надо, всё хорошо. Спасибо!

Comment: Я просто подумала, что комментарии отвлекают от темы, уводят в сторону. Но если нет, то пусть остаются.